# BorderLayout acting like a flow layout

Tags: java, user-interface, border-layout

I am having a hard time figuring out why this borderlayout is acting like a flowlayout still..

I tried this after first:

```
JPanel canvas = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
add(canvas);

text = new JLabel("hey");
canvas.add(text, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Then I tried this:

```
JPanel canvas = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
add(canvas)
JPanel canvasSouth = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
canvas.add(canvasSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

text = new JLabel("hey");
canvasSouth.add(text);
```

And then I said screw it, I am just going to throw everything down like this:

```
    JPanel canvas = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    add(canvas);

    JPanel canvasSouth = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    canvas.add(canvasSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JPanel canvasNorth = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    canvas.add(canvasNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel canvasEast = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    canvas.add(canvasEast, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JPanel canvasWest = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    canvas.add(canvasWest, BorderLayout.WEST);

    text = new JLabel("hey");
    canvasSouth.add(text);
```

I've had this problem before and never was able to fix it on my own. Hence I am asking you all. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `acting like a FlowLayout` ? Is it possible to upload an image with what is getting rendered ?

Comment: `why this borderlayout is acting like a flowlayout still..` - no idea what that means. What happened? What did you expect to happen? Post a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Four lines of code don't give us the context of how the code is used.

Comment: What is the layout of the parent container? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: When I say a flowlayout, I mean that when I put two labels next to eachother, they would both be right next to each other. The second one would be in the center and the first would be to the left of center. Here is a pastebin of the full code:
http://pastebin.com/XRhFVbj5 (non main)
http://pastebin.com/nuTXf6qA (main)

@YassinHajaj

Comment: @camickr      look above

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've posted two pastebin's with all of the info above

Comment: The `SSCCE` code should be posted here, not on pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a compound problem...

1. You add `canvas` to a `JPanel` which is still using a `FlowLayout`, which will use the `canvas`'s `preferredSize` to make determinations about how best to layout it out
2. You are adding empty `JPanel`'s to all the positions of the `BorderLayout`, since they have a default `preferredSize` of `0x0`, it's like you're not adding anything at all.  So the only thing that is providing any sizing hints to the `canvas` and it's parent container is the `JLabel`

Instead, ditch the `canvas`.  Simply set the layout of the parent container to `BorderLayout`.  Provide some sizing hints to the other components you are adding to the parent container.

[image: BorderLayout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class game extends JFrame {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public game() {
        nonMaingame canvas = new nonMaingame();
        setSize(1020, 720);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(canvas);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new game().setVisible(true);

    }

    public class nonMaingame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        /**
         *
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JLabel text;

        public nonMaingame() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel canvasSouth = makePanel(Color.RED);
            add(canvasSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            JPanel canvasNorth = makePanel(Color.BLUE);
            add(canvasNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel canvasEast = makePanel(Color.YELLOW);
            canvasEast.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            add(canvasEast, BorderLayout.EAST);

            JPanel canvasWest = makePanel(Color.MAGENTA);
            add(canvasWest, BorderLayout.WEST);

            text = new JLabel("hey");
            canvasSouth.add(text);
        }

        protected JPanel makePanel(Color color) {
            JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(100, 100);
                }
            };
            pane.setBackground(color);
            return pane;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect and makes a lot of sense.